# Linux, jack, analyze xrun callback cause

Tags: bitwig

**Os**, ubuntu 19.04.

**Audio server**, jack2.

**Question**, when I run jack2 and run music in audio application, jack log  sometimes return xrun callback (everytime, when crackling due playing audio). Is there any way to analyze what is cause of this xrun callback? For example which process caused this callbacks.

**Jack log**.

```
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Running
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Running
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Running
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
14:34:57.052 XRUN callback (1 skipped).
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Running
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
14:34:57.653 XRUN callback (48).
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
14:34:59.059 XRUN callback (1 skipped).
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Running
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
14:35:00.288 XRUN callback (50).
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Running
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
14:35:01.073 XRUN callback (2 skipped).
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Running
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = Bitwig Studio was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
14:35:03.080 XRUN callback (2 skipped).
```

Thanks.

**Update**

Seems problem is because gnome, because it takes quite a lot of cpu, when I doing something else during the playing from audio app. Is there any way to get best performance for audio app? At the exense of another applications.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199498/what-are-xruns

Comment: @PiedPiper Hello, I read about `xrun_debug`, but I don't have such as file in the `asound/SOUNDCARD/pcm0p` folder, even if I run jackd server.

Comment: Or could I setup this in qjacktl? In `Setup > Options > Statistics > Xrun detection regex`? What are the possibilities? I found this, https://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/list_of_jack_frame_period_settings_ideal_for_usb_interface. But option `( 16 / 48000 ) * 3 = 1` is absolute scifi for my card. Why? I have powerful notebook and usb2 interface. Thanks.

Comment: Seems problem is because gnome, because it takes quite a lot of cpu, when I doing something else during the playing from audio app. Is there any way to get best performance for audio app? At the exense of another applications.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165374/ubuntu-jack-maximum-priority-for-audio-application for best performance on Ubuntu.